# How to use a Spring @MessageMapping from properties to set an annotation attribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-messaging

I'm working with SQS spring-boot:spring-cloud,
I want to externalize the parameter, retrieve the value based on the active profile

```
@MessageMapping("static.queue")
public void receiveMessage(Payload payload) {
  // ...
}
```

is there any way to solve this problem?

something like

```
@MessageMapping("${properties.dynamic}")
public void receiveMessage(Payload payload) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try two options:

1. Use project `spring-could-aws`. You can annotate your SQS queue listener with [`@SqsAnnotation`](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_listener_endpoints).
2. Use JMS interface to access SQS queues. In such case you can use [plain Spring JMS features](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms-annotated) (e.g. `@JmsListener`).
3. [@MessageMapping](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/commit/4315c8f4ec3a54ec47a1149304bd3a8fb63e0f11) have support for expressions in MessageMapping annotation:

public class Example {

```
@MessageMapping("${spring.app}")
public void receiveMessage(Payload payload)  {
    // do
}}
```

in yml file:

```
spring:
  profiles: prod
  app: 'queueName1'

spring:
  profiles: dev
  app: 'queueName2'
```